# SUMPRODUCT that counts unique text values

Tags: excel, sum, product

I have a data set that roughly looks like this:

```
OpenDate      Name      FillDate      DaysToFill
12/05/13      Samuel        -           Open
01/01/14      Anne      01/16/14        16
01/12/14      Mike      01/25/14        13
01/28/14      Anne      01/31/14         3
```

I have a dashboard I am creating for metrics. There is a data validation list in which the user picks the month they want information about. This choice triggers a change in two cells -- R2 and R3. R2 corresponds to the month and generates the numeric value of that month (Jan =1, Feb = 2, etc) and R3 generates the last day in that month for the current year (Jan = 01/31/14, Feb = 02/28/14).

I have a formula that counts the number of entries that meet EITHER of the conditions below:

```
(i) DaysToFill > 0  AND FillDate is in the month chosen (in R2)
```

OR

```
(ii) DaysToFill = "Open" AND OpenDate < last day of month chosen (in R3)
```

I currently have the following sumproduct formula that calculates this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(DATA!I2:I30)),--(MONTH(DATA!I2:I30)=Sheet1!R2),

--(DATA!J2:J30>0))+SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(DATA!C2:C30)),

--((DATA!C2:C30)<=Sheet1!R3),--(DATA!J2:J30="Open"))
```

Where

Column C = OpenDate; Column I = FillDate; Column J = DaysToFill, and Column H (which isn't used here) is Name

This all works fine, but **I need a way to add the condition on the above formula -- I need a way to count the unique Names that meet those conditions.** So for the above data, if the user chooses January, the output for the formula I have is 4 [3 that meet the conditions in (i) and 1 that meets the conditions in (ii)]. But, if we get the additional layer of unique recruiters, I should get 3 (Because Anne is counted twice). I'm having a hard time seeing how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so, Anne should be counted once or shouldn't be counted at all?

Comment: Anne should be counted once. Its like a true/false -- if a unique name (here, Anne) either had a filled date in that month OR had an "Open" date prior to that month then they are counted once. So Anne is counted once for January.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(DATA!I2:I30)*(MONTH(DATA!I2:I30)=Sheet1!R2)*(DATA!J2:J30>0)+ISNUMBER(DATA!C2:C30)*(DATA!C2:C30<=Sheet1!R3)*(DATA!J2:J30="Open"),IF(H2:H30<>"",MATCH(H2:H30,H2:H30,0))),ROW(H2:H30)-ROW(H2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note that I'm not sure if your original formula has a flaw because `DATA!J2:J30>0` will return `TRUE` for any cells that contain "Open". Does that extra condition achieve anything, if `J2:J30` always contains a date or "Open" that part will return TRUE for everything.....

Comment: You are right about the TRUE -- I wouldn't have caught that. Turns out the dashboard I'm creating doesn't really need it anyway. I had used a nested IF statment to look at OpenDate -- so it was "" when opendate was empty, Open if there was no FillDate, and a number if there was a fill date. So even the "empty" values were turning up TRUE. But since you can't really sum non-numbers [the ISNUMBER was taking care of that], it wasn't immediately obvious. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick thoughts:
- Create a flag column that catenates the name and if the row matches the selection criteria.  First entry for example would be "Samuel.True"
In next column create enter the following formula

```
=if(row(<cell where name is>) = match(<cell where name is>&".True",<entire column created above>,0),1,0)
```

The idea being it will return 1 if it is the first matching name and valid selection, and 0 if not.

You can then sum that column and get the total of unique names that match the filter criteria.